# How to enable direct modifications to the system catalogues in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, database-administration

How to change the direct modification of system catalogues in sql ?

Comment: You **cannot** directly manipulate the system catalog views (the `sys.` schema) in SQL Server. They reflect the state of your database - you can *only* "manipulate" the system catalog views by manipulation your database objects

Comment: @marc_s ,is there a way to check its status

Comment: What status? Yes, you can **select** from all the catalog views as much as you want to "check the status" of whatever it is you're interested in - if your user has the proper permissions, that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In old versions of SQL Server (pre SQL 2005), it was possible to modify system tables directly by turning on the [`allow updates` configuration option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/allow-updates-server-configuration-option) and applying using `RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE`. This option is obsolete in SQL Server 2005 onward. Although it still exists, it is ignored.

You can check the configured value with the command below even though the option has no meaning in modern versions:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'allow updates';
```

Comment: what will happen if we  executed the above sp in modern version,

Comment: The script will show the currently configured value, not that it matters any since it's ignored.

Comment: `EXEC sp_configure 'allow updates',1 reconfigure with override` , while running this query the config value is changed to 1 . Does  that mean anything ?

Comment: @coffemug, the configured value as no significance as the documentation states, If you try updating a system table, the action will fail regardless of the setting.

Answer (score 1):

You "directly" modify the system catalogs by using DDL (data modification language).  These are commands that start with commands such as `ALTER`, `CREATE` and `DROP`.

These commands are well [documented](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848799(v=sql.110).aspx).

You should not even think about directly changing system tables/views otherwise.  They are owned by the database and managed by the database.

Comment: i got this from a checklist and what is mean by direct modification of system catalogues ?

Comment: @coffemug what is this "checklist" and where did you get it from? Point being, just because something is written down doesn't make it correct or safe.

Comment: @alroc ,we have a  list of standard to implement in our  servers. and its one of the rules we need to adhere

Comment: @coffemug per Dan’s answer it’s not even possible to do, so I’d suggest that this checklist be reviewed carefully for accuracy/applicability to current software if it’s suggesting that you do something that’s impossible, or change a configuration to block something that doesn’t need to be blocked.

Comment: @alroc , My checklist says, disable direct modification of system catalogues

Comment: @coffemug . . . Get a new checklist.  That one seems dangerous.